# Vite PWA auto update on page load, but perform regular update checks with user prompt

Tags: reactjs, angular, vite, progressive-web-apps

I want to configure the Vite PWA plugin so that it always loads the latest available version of my app when the user (re)loads the page.
When the app is loaded and the user navigates around, it should perform regular update checks and prompt the user to perform the update by clicking a button.

I implemented the last part like this:

```
  const {
    needRefresh: [needRefresh],
    updateServiceWorker,
  } = useRegisterSW({
    immediate: true,
    onRegisteredSW: (swUrl, r) => {
      r &&
        setInterval(async () => {
          if (!(!r.installing && navigator)) return;

          if ('connection' in navigator && !navigator.onLine) return;

          const resp = await fetch(swUrl, {
            cache: 'no-store',
            headers: {
              cache: 'no-store',
              'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            },
          });

          if (resp?.status === 200) await r.update();
        }, 60 * 1000);
    },
  });
```

When `needRefresh` is true, I show an update prompt to the user.

My `vite.config.ts` looks like this:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'prompt',
      ...
    }),
  ],
});
```

The problem with this implementation is, that it always needs the user's interaction to perform an update, but I want the application to auto-update when for example the user leaves and opens the page at a later time.
I cannot use `registerType: 'autoUpdate'` in the vite config, as it automatically updates and reloads the page when I perform my periodical update checks from the first snippet. This is bad UX and could lead to data loss and user frustration.

I know from the [Angular Service worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config), one can use the strategy `freshness` to always load the newest version available on the server on page load, and still perform periodical update checks without automatically reloading the page.

I could not find a similar option in the Vite PWA configuration. Am I missing something or is there some other way how I can do that?